# Why do I get Unknown target error when attempting to send a Google Universal Analytics Event with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am attempting to send an event to Google Universal Analytics:

```
ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'calculator-interaction',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: 'calculate-button'
});
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Running command: ga("send", [object Object])
analytics.js:31 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

The Google Universal Analytics is being included in the page via Google Tag Manager if that makes a difference?

Comment: i think there is a related question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765806/existing-google-analytics-events-and-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ga needs a tracker object to send commands. Are you using `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto')`?

If yes, you might be specifying a named tracker instead. In this case, you will need to target it specifically by calling `ga('name_of_the_tracker.send', options)`